# How hard is the comprehensive examination based masters in Computer Science?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, computer-science

I wish to apply for an MS in computer science in the United States as an international student. I see that some universities (UC San Diego) provide either a thesis track or a comprehensive exam track for the MS programme. I can see that it is mentioned that there are limited attempts to take the comprehensive exam which takes place at the end of the degree program, failing which a student would be deregistered from the programme. I am somewhat new to this concept of comprehensive exam as it is absent in my country. While I understand that it is University specific, can the comprehensive exam based Masters Programme be challenging due to the examination at the end which decides whether the student is qualified to graduate.

Answer (score 3):

I took comprehensive exams and remember them to be quite difficult.  However, I get the impression that every school makes their own exams - there is no "standard" comprehensive exam.  So maybe one school is hard and the other easy.

It is a high-stakes exam because there are limited attempts.  I remember when sitting for my comprehensive exams seeing students I did not know.  That was scary because it meant that these students had failed the comps the first time around.  Being that they had otherwise finished the program they went on with their lives and came back to take another swing at passing the exam and getting their degree.  That was not a position I wanted to be in.

As an international student, traveling back to university at a future time after your studies have formally ended may be even more difficult than for a domestic student.  The border guards may/may not understand retaking comprehensive exams.

You should be aware going in that failure is always a possibility.

I was happy to have passed my comprehensive exams.  When time was called, I had not even read all of the questions and I was dead tired (the exam lasted all day).  But evidently I had read and answered enough of the questions to pass.